# "J'ai beaucoup parlé" or "J'ai parlé beaucoup"?

Tags: ordre-des-mots, adverbes

> J'ai beaucoup parlé hier.
>
> J'ai parlé beaucoup hier.

Are both sentences correct? If so, is there a difference in meaning? Is it that in the first sentence, "beaucoup" modifies the action of speaking, while in the second, it modifies the result of speaking (i.e., the words)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct saying is :

> J'ai beaucoup parlé hier.

"Parler" is already the general action of saying words. So you can't really quantify the result.

You could however put "beaucoup" after the verb "dire" :

> J'ai dit beaucoup de bêtises.

As "dire" doesn't necessarily imply *words* (it could be prayers, speeches, etc.).

In most cases (if not all), "beaucoup" precedes the verb if the object isn't specified :

> J'ai beaucoup mangé.
>
> J'ai mangé beaucoup de bacon.

Comment: *Je parle beaucoup aujourd'hui*. So maybe it's only with composed tenses?

Comment: But in a familiar level of language, *J'ai parlé beaucoup* will be often said. Said differently, writing it could let think that have little education.