# “J'ai beaucoup lu” or “J'ai lu beaucoup”?

Tags: adverbes, ordre-des-mots

> J'ai beaucoup lu hier.
>
> J'ai lu beaucoup hier.

Which sentence is correct? When we have [*parler*](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/22839/jai-beaucoup-parl%C3%A9-or-jai-parl%C3%A9-beaucoup) instead of *lu*, it should be placed after *beaucoup*. But for reading, we can quantify the result -- reading a lot (of text, etc.). So are both sentences correct, with the first one putting the emphasis on the action of reading and the second one on the quantity being read?

Comment: Having *parler* or *lire* doesn't make a difference on where to have *beaucoup*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"J'ai beaucoup lu" est plus correct s'il n'y a pas de complément. Mais on dira "J'ai lu beaucoup de livres".

Comment: «J'en ai lu beaucoup» ou «J'en ai beaucoup lu»?

Comment: Il y a une nuance: «J'en ai lu beaucoup»: beaucoup de livres, mais pas forcément beaucoup de temps, «J'en ai beaucoup lu»: beaucoup de temps, mais pas forcement beaucoup de livres. Du Tolstoï, j'en ai beaucoup lu, des questions sur StackOverflow, j'en ai lu beaucoup :)

Comment: C'est intéressant.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are correct

"with the first one putting the emphasis on the action of reading and the second one on the quantity being read"

That's exactly that ;)