# Position of "trop" in composed tense

Tags: ordre-des-mots, adverbes, passé-composé

In composed tense, should *trop* go before or after the main verb?

> J'ai trop lu/parlé hier.

or

> J'ai lu/parlé trop hier.

With [beaucoup](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/22839/jai-beaucoup-parl%C3%A9-or-jai-parl%C3%A9-beaucoup), the adverb goes before the main verb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second form doesn't work at all. You need to use:

> J'ai trop lu/parlé hier.

You might be able to say, write:

> J'ai lu/parlé hier. Trop.

But that is quite different from your initial question. There are now two sentences, the second one introducing a precision, and there's a style effect that IMHO is not in the scope of your initial question.